# integrality of coefficients of the quotients of $1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} q^{a^{n}}$ and $1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} q^{b^{n}}$

Tags: analysis

Let 
$$\lambda(q,a) = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} q^{a^{n}}$$ 
and
$$\mu(q,a) = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} q^{a^{n}}$$

Where $|q|<1$ on $\mathbb{C}$. Let $b,c$ are naturals greater than two such that $b\neq c$

Preliminary numerical investigation suggests that the following four quotients have MacLaurin series with integer coefficients:

- $\lambda(q,c)/\mu(q,b)$
- $\mu(q,b)/\lambda(q,c)$
- $\lambda(q,c)/\lambda(q,b)$
- $\mu(q,c)/\mu(q,b)$

Is there a straightforward way of (dis-)proving integrality of the coefficients? (preferably one which doesn't necessitate explicit calculation of the derivatives at $q=0$)

Comment: In the denominator you always have a series with leading coefficient equal to $1$. So, in the long division you are always dividing by $1$ to get the coefficients.

Comment: To get the coefficients you can do long division of the series. This is like the long division you do for polynomials but you organize, of course, the powers of $q$ by increasing exponents. Then you divide the terms of smallest exponent. That is why the constant term of the denominator is always used in the division to find the next term. Since this constant coefficient is $1$ in all those cases, you get always divisions by $1$, which give you integer coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

Quotients of all kind like $\frac{\lambda}{\mu}$ will have integral coefficients, as leading term a formal power series is unit implies the formal power series has an inverse in the ring $\mathbb{Z}((q))$. You may look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Dividing_series).